# your connection is insecure

Tags: internet-explorer, certificate

We have some Win 7 clients on our network and same updated OS and IE version on them and connected to same NTP server. When we connect to a secure website (HTTPS) from mentioned clients, we will see various reactions; some of them connect and open website normally and others show security caution which included "there are issues with the site's certificate chain(net::ERR_cert_authority_invalid)

It is necessary to tell that I checked certificate publisher on IE and find the intermediate certificate authority of certificate chain in website can not be seen in which have problem.
How is it possible from same updated OS and IE clients, we can see different messages?

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the following steps:

1. Open Internet Options in IE.
2. Click the Advanced tab.
3. Under "Security",uncheck "Check for publisher's certificate revocation" and "Check for server certificate revocation."
4. Click Apply.
5. Click Ok.
6. Close and relaunch Internet Explorer.

This will help you to fix the error message of certificate in IE.